# Adding v-model to v-dialog breaks the element in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i have an `array apps` and every `app` has a `link`. I also have a component, `Dialog`. After adding `v-model="dialog"`, to be able to close the dialog from the ChildComponent
`Dialog` my apps doesn't work anymore. Ass you can see i'm adding the current app as a prop to Dialog, but after adding the `v-model` on the `v-dialog` it always sends the last app in the `apps array`. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

`Parent component`

```
<v-col  v-for="app in apps" :key="app._id" :cols="setBreakpointCols">
      <v-card class="pa-2 " outlined height="230px">
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on: dialog, attrs }">
            <v-tooltip right color="#363636" max-width="250px">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on: tooltip }">
                <v-img :src="getImgUrl(app.src)" class="white--text align-end"
                  gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(0,0,0,.5)" height="85%" v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...dialog }">
                  <v-card-title v-text="app.title"></v-card-title>
                </v-img>
              </template>
              <span v-if="app.vpnRequired">VPN needed to run!</span>
              <v-divider class="my-1" v-if="app.vpnRequired" dark ></v-divider>
              <span>{{ app.description }}</span>
            </v-tooltip>
            <!-- shows the link of the clicked app (for example the second of 5) in the array-->
          <h1>{{app.link}}</h1>
          </template>
          <!-- shows the link of the last ( 5 of 5) app in the array. Why is this link different then the app.link from 2 lines up?-->
          <h1>{{app.link}}</h1>
          <Dialog @closeDialog="closeDialog" :app="app" />
        </v-dialog>
        <v-card-actions mb-2>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-tooltip top color="#363636">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" v-if="app.quickActions">
              <v-btn @click="DeleteAppFromQuickActions(app)" icon>
                <v-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" >
                  mdi-minus-box-outline
                </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" v-else>
              <v-btn @click="AddAppToQuickActions(app)" icon>
                <v-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                  mdi-plus-box-outline
                </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span v-if="app.quickActions">Delete from QuickActions</span>
            <span v-else>Add to QuickActions</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
```

`child component`

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col fixed style="background:#363636;" class="d-flex justify-end" cols="12">
        <v-btn plain color="grey" :href="app.link" target="_blank">
          <v-icon>mdi-open-in-new</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="closeDialog" plain color="grey">
          <v-icon>mdi-close-box-outline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <iframe :src="app.link" width="100%" height="800px"
          frameborder="0">
        </iframe>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Dialog",
  props: ['app'],
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeDialog: function (){
      this.$emit('closeDialog')
    }
  }


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to create a modal component for each item in a for-loop.

*Because when we create modals in for-loop then all modals' components have been created separately but they all are binding with the same `v-model`, so the last `v-model` will always be active and pass only the last item's data.*

This problem can also be fixed by passing the array index or creating a separate v-model using an object but **The good practice is to keep the modal component outside of for loop and use it accordingly by passing data of each selected item as a prop.**

That means you can do it like this-
(I used dummy data to create the UI)

**PARENT COMPONENT-**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- To open dialog on click on any item -->
        <Dialog
            v-if="dialog && selectedApp"
            v-model="dialog"
            :app="selectedApp"
            @closeDialog="closeDialog"
        />

        <!-- Loop on items -->
        <v-col v-for="app in apps" :key="app._id" cols="12">
            <v-card class="pa-2 " outlined height="230px">
                <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on: dialog, attrs }">
                        <v-tooltip right color="#363636" max-width="250px">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on: tooltip }">
                                <v-img
                                    :src="app.src"
                                    class="white--text align-end"
                                    gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
                                    height="85%"
                                    v-bind="attrs"
                                    v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...dialog }"
                                    @click="selectedApp = app"
                                >
                                    <v-card-title v-text="app.title"></v-card-title>
                                </v-img>
                            </template>
                            <span v-if="app.vpnRequired">VPN needed to run!</span>
                            <v-divider class="my-1" v-if="app.vpnRequired" dark></v-divider>
                            <span>{{ app.description }}</span>
                        </v-tooltip>
                        <!-- shows the link of the clicked app (for example the second of 5) in the array-->
                        <h1>{{ app.link }}</h1>
                    </template>
                    <!-- shows the link of the last ( 5 of 5) app in the array. Why is this link different then the app.link from 2 lines up?-->
                    <h1>{{ app.link }}</h1>
                </v-dialog>
                <v-card-actions mb-2>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-tooltip top color="#363636">
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" v-if="app.quickActions">
                            <v-btn @click="DeleteAppFromQuickActions(app)" icon>
                                <v-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                    mdi-minus-box-outline
                                </v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" v-else>
                            <v-btn @click="AddAppToQuickActions(app)" icon>
                                <v-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                    mdi-plus-box-outline
                                </v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                        <span v-if="app.quickActions">Delete from QuickActions</span>
                        <span v-else>Add to QuickActions</span>
                    </v-tooltip>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Dialog from "/var/www/html/weresearchfrontend/src/Dialog.vue";

export default {
    name: "ParentComponent",

    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
            selectedApp: null,
            apps: [
                {
                    title: "A",
                    vpnRequired: true,
                    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/1900x800",
                    description: "Hello Google",
                    link: "https://google.com",
                    quickActions: true,
                },
                {
                    title: "B",
                    vpnRequired: true,
                    src: "https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100",
                    description: "Hello Github",
                    link: "https://github.com",
                    quickActions: true,
                },
            ],
        };
    },

    components: {
        Dialog,
    },

    methods: {
        closeDialog: function() {
            this.dialog = false;
            // reset selected app also
            this.selectedApp = app;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**CHILD COMPONENT (DIALOG COMPONENT)-**

```
<template>
    <v-dialog :value="value">
        <v-card>
            <v-container fluid>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col fixed style="background:#363636;" class="d-flex" cols="12">
                        <span class="white--text font-weight-bold"
                            >{{ app.title }} > {{ app.description }} > {{ app.link }}</span
                        >
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-btn plain color="grey" :href="app.link" target="_blank">
                            <v-icon>mdi-open-in-new</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                        <v-btn @click="$emit('closeDialog')" plain color="grey">
                            <v-icon>mdi-close-box-outline</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <iframe :src="app.link" width="100%" height="800px" frameborder="0">
                        </iframe>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Dialog",

    props: ["value", "app"],
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Neha for your answer. What is the value prop you are using in the dialog as props? I dont see any prop you are passing, only the app.

Comment: when we use v-model on any custom component then it became a prop in that component and is used as the name "value". For example, I used `v-model="dialog"` so this dialog variable will be passed as a prop in the `<Dialog>` component which will be referred to by the "value" prop. For more understanding read this- https://localazy.com/blog/v-model-support-without-requiring-value-prop

Comment: I see thanks. Trying your solution opens 2 dialogs. The first 1 you specified on the parent component: Dialog. And the second 1 is where  <h1>{{ app.link }}</h1> is put. If you see the documentation the dialog html should be specified after the template where i put <h1>{{ app.link }}</h1>. 

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/